# I need input on how to architect this project

Tags: architecture

So, we are creating a document management system on top of sharepoint.  We have about 20,000 clients that will have documents associated with each.

Where I am stuck is I am not sure how to go about building this.  What I want to do, is create 30 site collections (this way we will have 30 content databases) and spread the 20,000 clients evenly across these 30 site collections so we will have about 666 sites per site collection.  This way each site will be a container for that client's documents.

The problem with this approach is that we will never know a client's URL.  For example,

```
Client A could live at this URL: docs/SiteCollection3/ClientA and
Client B could live at this URL: docs/SiteCollection23/ClientB
```

We want the URL's to be consistant for the use of an Outlook add in called harmon.ie.

So then we were thinking to create a sitecollection per client (still have 30 content databases) and this way we can keep the URLs consistant.  But this way seems wicked overkill.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How many documents per client?  How much space do they take up?  Is this pretty much consistent across all clients or is there a lot of variability?  Is the number/size of the client documents expected to rise dramatically over time?  What are your security requirements? Have you considered using metadata instead of separate sites?  There ar elikely a lot more questions you need to consider but these are off the top of my head.  Consier revising your question with as much info as can think of.

Comment: A client is a company that everyone in our firm will have access to.  The problem is, 1% of our clients will sometimes need only a few people with access.  There could be as many as 1000 documents per client.  We don't want to use metadata because we want to spread the processing over multiple content databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a site collection for every client.  This allows you maximum flexibility in planning your content databases, and provides a nice security box if you need that.  It will also give you the URL configurability you need. The most site collections I've ever seen in a web app is about 5000 (but with a LOT of content), but [Technet says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28v=office.14%29.aspx) 250,000 site collections and 300 content DBs are supported and meets their benchmark testing.

You'll want to check out that technet link to understand more about the boudaries and limitations you may encounter.